# I want install multi DE, but with a controlled loader and purg?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments

I want install more than one DE on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I got many problems, you can read here to know what happened excatly: https://askubuntu.com/questions/854141/manny-problems-i-got-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-about-lock-and-pakage-broken-and-uncont?noredirect=1#comment1314223_854141

So, How do I install multi DE, but with a controlled loader and purg ?

Comment: It is easier to install them then to remove them. I would try them in  a VM most people settle into one they like.

Comment: I know it is easy to install, but I want is it may cause any conflict?, if yes what should I do?.

let suppose I installed gnome 3, and then Cinnamon, or should install KDE  5 plasma before Cinnamon and MATE? ... like this ...

Comment: I do not anticipate conflict and if there is a problem you would file a bug report. The main problem is duplicate apps.

Comment: Then, is it recommended begin with gnome 3 and KDE 5 plasma?
note: I checked if there is any duplicated software updater but nothing

Comment: I think the recommended DE is Unity. Other DE are supported. Beyond that is is an opinion. Try them, use the one you like most, and report any problems you have.

Comment: unity is a default DE, but I asked is it recommended begin with gnome 3 and KDE 5 plasma? I meant install first gnome 3 and kde

Comment: There are no formal recommendations just opinions. Try as many as you wish and use the one(s) you like the most.